# dahdi не находит заголовочных файлов linux-а

Tags: linux

Подскажите как установить исходники для 4.4 ядра,не могу установить пакеты так как пишут что нет исходников для 4.4

UPDATE:

```
libselinux1:amd64 
linux-firmware                            1.127.23                                             
linux-generic-lts-xenial                  4.4.0.57.44                                          
linux-headers-4.4.0-57                    4.4.0-57.78~14.04.1                                  
linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic            4.4.0-57.78~14.04.1                                  
linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial          4.4.0.57.44                                          
llinux-image-4.4.0-57-generic             4.4.0-57.78~14.04.1                                  
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic        4.4.0-57.78~14.04.1                                  
linux-image-generic-lts-xenial            4.4.0.57.44                                         
linux-libc-dev:amd64                      3.13.0-106.153                                      
linux-source                              3.13.0.106.114                                       
linux-source-3.13.0                       3.13.0-106.153                                       
util-linux    

make -C linux all
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.1+2.11.1/linux'
make -C drivers/dahdi/firmware firmware-loaders
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.1+2.11.1/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.1+2.11.1/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
You do not appear to have the sources for the 4.4.0-57-generic kernel installed.
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.1+2.11.1/linux'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Версию бубунты при этом надо держать в секрете. Никому не говори!

Comment: Чем https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ не нравится?

Comment: не то что не нравится,я не могу под него пакеты установить.Версия ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Ок, следующий вопрос: почему именно 4.4?

Comment: Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-57-generic  вот на данный момент у меня установлено что,пытаюсь установить пакет пишут нет исходников для установленной версии ядра

Comment: *Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-57-generic* — здесь присутствует версия пакета с программой linux, а вас вообще-то спрашивали про версию дистрибутива. см. вывод `$ lsb_release -a`

Comment: Что-то я не могу понять - в чём проблема? Выходит сообщение **нет исходников для установленной версии ядра** ? Ну так - установите! Добавьте source репозитарии, у Вас появятся пакеты с суффиксом src, установите пакет с исходами ядра - всё будет сделано аккуратно.

Comment: Спасибо попробую

Comment: А как установить исходники из сурсов? Из репозитория только 3.13 загружается